# Change Django site display name using the manage.py shell?

Tags: django

I have a django application where its site domain name is example.com. How can I change its Display name using the manage.py shell? I been looking thorough the “sites” framework for a method but I cannot find anything

Comment: What do you mean "display name", are you trying to change a domain name from a web application running on that domain?..

Comment: If I go to http://localhost/myApp/admin/sites/site/1/ I can change the "Display name". At the moment is example.com. That's the one I would like to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/

In your shell do

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

site = Site.objects.get(name='example.com')
# or
site = Site.objects.get(id=1)
site.name = 'my_shiny_name'
site.save()
```